# AS3: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Updated:

Now I am recieving this error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: **Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip**

From this class:

```
package com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Wheel extends MovieClip
    {

        public function Wheel(area:MovieClip, diagram:MovieClip)
        {
            area.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        }
        private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("wheel clicked");
            trace("this is diagram");
        }

    }

}
```

and this script:

```
import com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components.*;

var wheel:Wheel = new Wheel(this.wheel,this.car);
```

Debug gives:

```
Attempting to launch and connect to Player using URL C:/Documents and Settings/reithg/My Documents/Classes/com/GeorgesMegaAmazingApp-app.xml
[SWF] GeorgesMegaAmazingApp.swf - 51681 bytes after decompression
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@2968e51 to com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components.Wheel.
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at GeorgesMegaAmazingApp_fla::MainTimeline()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
    at runtime::AppRunner/run()
    at ADLAppEntry/run()
    at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
```

GeorgesMegaAmazingApp-app.xml doesn't exist in that directory but I don't know why it is looking there anyway, it is not where the fla is located.

Comment: have you tried to say `import com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components.Wheel` instead of `com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components.*`?

Comment: @Eugeny89 the problem was with the capitalisation of the first letter as I had saved the file as all lowercase... but now I have a new error, updating first post.

Comment: it doesnt say a popup appears with this: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@2963e51 to com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components.Wheel.
 at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
 at flash.display::Sprite()
 at flash.display::MovieClip()
 at GeorgesMegaAmazingApp_fla::MainTimeline()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
 at runtime::AppRunner/run()
 at ADLAppEntry/run()
 at global/runtime::ADLEntry()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `this.wheel` or `this.car` is not a `MovieClip`. Also could you turn on debugging in File > Publish Settings? You'll then get better error messages because, without more information, your error could be just about anywhere.

**Edit:**

Try renaming `var wheel` to something else because it seems that Flash is confused with your two wheel objects. For example, try:

```
var wheelObject:Wheel = new Wheel(this.wheel,this.car);
```

Comment: `[object MovieClip]
[object MovieClip]` is the result of `trace(this.wheel);
trace(this.car);`

Comment: Ok but so far all we know is that somewhere, at an unknown line, something is not a MovieClip. If you turn on debugging you'll have line numbers and will know exactly where your error is (and probably won't need to ask on SO).

Comment: These are the only lines in the whole movie... updating first post with debugging

Answer (score 1):

Is Wheel.as in the directory com/George/MegaAmazingApp/Components? (case-sensitive)
Is that 'com' directory in a source path directory?

Comment: yes code hinting is working in my other file, so when I type wheel it tells me I need an area and a diagram in the code hint.

Comment: nevermind the w was lowercase causing it to fail, but got a new error could you take a look?